# Specific entry type in entry field

Tags: entry, field, relatedto

This seems like an easy question to answer but I can't seem to figure it out... I'm sure we could do it in Craft 2. Anyway, I'm trying to figure out how to only display a certain entry type in an entry field. For example, I have an entry field labeled "Authors" and in my articles section I want to select and entry from that field to relate to an article, however if I add an entry field to the article entry type, all my entries can be selected... how do I limit it to only the entry type "authors"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a dumb question, I just missed the greyed out checkbox with sources in the field settings.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else wants to get even more granular, the [Entries Subset plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/entriessubset) works well. You can narrow the options to specific entry types, entries by specific authors, and more.